# counting no of exams a student has appeared in exam combining two tables

Tags: mysql, count

I have two below tables student and examination:
Student table:

```
Id   Name
1    Samantha
2    Jane
3    Bob
4    Scarlet
5    David
```

Examination:

```
student_id   subject
1     Biology
1     physics
3     history
4     geography
4     geography
```

Now I need to find which student has appeared in which examination how many number of times, the exact ans I expect is:

```
student.id examination.subject no_of_times
1          biology      1
1          physics      1
3          history      1
4          geography    2
```

I have tried below query, but got wrong ans:

```
select Student.id, examination.subject, count(*) from Student join examination Student.id = examination.student_id;
```

Please help me to write the correct query to get correct expected output!!

Thank You!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your exact query, we don't even need to join, we can just use the second `Examination` table exclusively:

```sql
SELECT student_id, subject, COUNT(*) AS no_of_times
FROM Examination
GROUP BY student_id, subject;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query for your question

```
SELECT
    s.ID AS STUDENT_ID,
    e.SUBJECT,
    COUNT(e.SUBJECT) AS NUMBER_OF_TIMES
FROM
    STUDENT s
JOIN
    EXAMINATION e ON s.ID = e.STUDENT_ID
GROUP BY
    s.ID,
    e.SUBJECT;
```